# Bind a object value into a component when TouchableOpacity Avatar pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My goal is to display the overlay bound to that button when the baby avatar is clicked.
Let me know how to fix it.

```
      const OverlayForm = ({ baby }) => {
        return <BabyProfile baby={baby} />;
      }

      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <View style={styles.main}>
            {Babies.map((baby: Baby, index) => (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={() => {
                    toggleOverlay;
                    myValue = baby;
                  }}
                  key={index}
                >
                  <AvatarData baby={baby} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ))}
            <Overlay isVisible={visible} onBackdropPress={toggleOverlay}>
              {OverlayForm(myValue)}
            </Overlay>
          </View>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

[image]

I solved as this by Quentin Grisel's advice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the overlay inside your Baby avatar component and simply change its state to display/hide the overlay.

```
export default function App() {
  return <BabyAvatar overlay={false} />;
}

const BabyAvatar = () => {
  const [isOverlayed, setIsOverlayed] = React.useState(false);

  const displayOverlay = () => setIsOverlayed(!isOverlayed);

  return (
    <>
    <Text>Baby overlay: {isOverlayed ? 'true':'false'}</Text>
    <Button onPress={() => displayOverlay()} title="Change overlay" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your way was right. Implementing overlays in child components is a bit simpler and easier :)